# Received an invalid header name: '#<FCGI'. in c# when I try to get data from a server

Tags: c#, html, http, fastcgi

I'm trying to connect from a C# app to a web server and I want to get values from it and save it to a data base. This server has a login, so I'm trying to replicate the browser behaviour, when I send the login request, I get an exception `System.Net.Requests` with the mesage: *Received an invalid header name: '#<FCGI'.*

I've tried to add the header with the sentence: `request.Headers.Add("#<FCGI:");`, but I get a new `System.Net.WebHeaderCollection` exception, with the following message: *Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters. (Parameter 'name')*.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp($"http://{this.ipaddr}/app/app.app?cmd=authority_login&username=user&userpass=password");
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.ContentType="application/json";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("#<FCGI:");
WebResponse response1 = request.GetResponse();
```

I captured the trafic with the server with
[Wireshark (picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QspKP.png), and the full header is

```
#<FCGI: :CGI:0x405b5068 @output_hidden=nil, @cookies={"sid"=>["ad7ee82e6731416ef7f1d0e80b266906"], "dispzone"=>["client"], "lang"=>["en"]}, @args=nil, @multipart=false, @output_cookies=nil, @params={"username"=>["User"], "cmd"=>["authority_login"], "userpass"=>["espec"]}, @request=#<FCGI::Request:0x405b5230 @id=1, @out=#<StringIO:0x405b50e0>, @in=#<StringIO:0x405b5170>, @data=#<StringIO:0x405b5140>, @env={"SERVER_NAME"=>"192.168.30.146", "HTTP_HOST"=>"192.168.30.146", "HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"lighttpd/1.4.13", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"192.168.30.29", "PATH_INFO"=>"", "SERVER_ADDR"=>"192.168.30.146", "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"/app/app.app", "HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"=>"1", "HTTP_COOKIE"=>"lang=en; dispzone=client; sid=ad7ee82e6731416ef7f1d0e80b266906", "REMOTE_PORT"=>"51580", "REQUEST_URI"=>"/app/app.app?cmd=authority_login&username=User&userpass=password", "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", "PATH"=>"/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin", "DOCUMENT_ROOT"=>"/espec/html/", "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "SCRIPT_FILENAME"=>"/espec/html/app/app.app", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.1", "QUERY_STRING"=>"cmd=authority_login&username=User&userpass=password", "REDIRECT_STATUS"=>"200", "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"gzip, deflate", "HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"keep-alive"}, @err=#<StringIO:0x405b50b0>>>
```

I get a warning message from Wireshark saying that *Illegal characters found in header name*. Is there a way to "skip" this header so my app can read the content of the web?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error suggest that the server responds with an incorrect http header, so adding it to the request won't solve anything. Can you capture the http-request/response in Wireshark?

Comment: Already include the Wireshark capture! Thanks for the comment

Comment: What web-server are you using to serve the http requests? It looks like the webserver executes the request against FastCGI but the result is inserted into the HTTP header which results in an invalid header.

Comment: The web server is lighttpd/1.4.13, unfortunately I have no access to its configuration, because it is the web server of a RS-485 to LAN converter, and only works with a web browser

Comment: Since the error originates on the server side there might not be much you can do about it.  You could try using a raw TCP socket instead and process all the HTTP traffic manually. Question is if the browser also receives this mangled header and how it handles it. Are you trying to communicate with the serial bus? I've worked with Moxa and Aten RS-485 gateways before but only ever used raw ports.

Comment: As far as I know, the browser receives and process this header, but I don't really know how it works, I guess the browser uses a CGI engine. On the other part, I can't use the serial bus because the operator who uses the machine uses this web server and it's not possible to disconect it, so I would try to use a raw TCP socket. Thank you!